# How to prevent someone having your TeamViewer ID from seeing your computer status

Tags: privacy

I've noticed something that is a little strange with TeamViewer. If someone has a TeamViewer account, he/she can add a partner by using an ID only, and then always see that partner's status, meaning whether the computer is online or offline.

I haven't figured TeamViewer's security model, so I am wondering how could someone prevent that.

For example, let's say I am running TeamViewer and I gave someone my ID. We did a session once and it's over. My password was changed and the partner can no longer connect to my computer. However, my ID remains the same. Thus, the partner can always watch my status, when my computer is online and when offline. Isn't there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same problem and found a way by browsing through the options. You should select Extras>Options, then Advanced, click on Show advanced options, then tick the field "Hide online status for this TeamViewer ID" in the subsection: "Advanced settings for Computers and Contacts".

This way, you can still connect to your computer, but it will be displayed as offline to users having your ID.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess that's the only way you can do it, but still it's not ideal. What if I wanted regular contacts to be able to see my online status but not everyone I have ever done a session with.

Comment: Sadly that is the only way that I found, but if you manage to find a better solution, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to Extras > Options > Computers & Contacts and tick the checkbox "Only partners in my list may see my online status and send messages to me".

Then only the contacts you've added to your Computers & Contacts list will be able to see your online status (and send messages to you).